# How can I grab an element's attr data in angular with jqlite?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, jqlite

How can I grab an element's attr data in angular with jqlite?

html,

```
<button ng-click="loadForm($event)" href="form.php">Load Directive Form</button>
<div data-my-form></div>
```

angular,

```
     app.directive('myForm', function() {
        return {
          controller:function($scope){
            $scope.isLoaded = false;
            $scope.loadForm = function(e){

                console.log(e.target.attr('href')); // error 

                var form = e.target.attr('href'); // error

                $scope.isLoaded = true;
            }
          },
          template: '<div><div ng-if="isLoaded" ng-include="'+ form +'" ></div></div>',
          link:function(scope, element) {

          }
        }
    });
```

I get this error,

```
TypeError: e.target.attr is not a function
```

any ideas?

Comment: Use `e.target.href` or `e.target.getAttribute('href')`, depending on whether or not you want the absolute or relative link. Still I wonder why do you assign _href_ attribute to a non-link element.

Comment: i get this error `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'HTMLDivElement' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object HTMLDivElement]] starting at [HTMLDivElement]].`

Comment: `form` variable is defined as local to controller function, yet you attempt to use it in the template.

Comment: Aww I see. I get null anyway with `e.target.href;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`attr()` is method available on jqLite elements.

`e.target` is a reference to a DOM element.

You need to wrap the DOM element as a jqLite element first:

```
var form = angular.element(e.target).attr('href');
```